# I'm trying to build Apache Hadoop 2.5.0 on Windows 7 x64 but I keep running into an unknown error

Tags: windows, apache, maven, hadoop, javadoc

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.8
.1:jar (module-javadocs) on project hadoop-maven-plugins: MavenReportException:
Error while creating archive:

[ERROR] Exit code: 1 - C:\hsc\hadoop-maven-plugins\src\main\java\org\apache\hado
op\maven\plugin\util\Exec.java:45: error: unknown tag: String

[ERROR] * @param command List<String> containing command and all arguments

[ERROR] ^

[ERROR] C:\hsc\hadoop-maven-plugins\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\maven\plugin
\util\Exec.java:46: error: unknown tag: String

[ERROR] * @param output List<String> in/out parameter to receive command output

[ERROR] ^

[ERROR] C:\hsc\hadoop-maven-plugins\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\maven\plugin
\util\FileSetUtils.java:50: error: unknown tag: File

[ERROR] * @return List<File> containing every element of the FileSet as a File

[ERROR] ^

[ERROR]

[ERROR] Command line was: C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\jre\..\bin\javadoc.exe @o
ptions @packages

[ERROR]

[ERROR] Refer to the generated Javadoc files in 'C:\hsc\hadoop-maven-plugins\tar
get' dir.

[ERROR] -> [Help 1]

[ERROR]

[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.

[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

[ERROR]

[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:

[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception

[ERROR]

[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command

[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :hadoop-maven-plugins
```

Prior to this, I've run into the usual error where it asks for file read/write access. I've given it all the permissions through chmod as well as manually changing the permission settings in the file properties on windows.

The wiki link sends me to a page that basically says its a problem with the plugin. Unfortunately, there isn't anything there that would indicate how to fix the problem.

I'm on Windows 7x64, trying to build hadoop 2.5.0 using src and using latest version of maven 3.2.3 and jdk 1.8.0_20

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue while building the source. Instead of using the following command for compiling:

```
mvn package -Pdist,native -DskipTests=true -Dtar
```

I used:

```
mvn package -Pdist,native -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -DskipTests -Dtar
```

Do try this!

Answer (score 1):

You can also add below property in parent POM to resolve this issue -

```
<properties>
    <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
</properties>
```